# Publishing Debug Symbols in TFS Build

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Using TFS 2013 It is a simple matter to generate debug symbols as part of the build process by entering a location into the ‘Path to publish symbols’ field of the build definition. Unfortunately I can’t use any of the TFS build environment variables to specify the drop location for the symbols in the ‘Path to publish symbols’ field because symbol publishing takes place after the build is done and those variables are apparently no longer in scope. So I specified a Debug folder in a fixed location and was going to move it to the desired location with the PostBuild script. Even that does not work because the symbols are not yet present when the postbuild script runs. The order of events is (roughly):
1. Run prebuild script
2. Build
3. Run postbuild script
4. Tests
5. Generate symbols
It looks like this is typically accomplished with yet another server… a Symbols Server. Is that what everyone does?

I notice that the information to determine the proper location to save the files (for me anyway) can easily be found using information in ..\000Admin\server.txt. Using that info I could have the postbuild script wait (say… up to an hour) for the symbols to appear (they should be there in a minute). Then move the Debug folder from the fixed location to the proper location. Is there a better way?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question or the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol server / symbol share is a separate thing from the drop location. It's structured in a specific way the Debugger understands and allows one to debug an application without having to ship the .pdb files with the application.

Since you may want to provide other parties access to your symbol server (similar to how Microsoft allows access to their symbol servers for most of the .NET framework), then you can simply tell them the location and optionally the credentials needed to access them.

The symbol share is not really meant for human consumption, it's all built up with GUIDs and hashes so that the debugger can find its way around easily and quickly. It's also structured so that multiple versions of the same symbol are stored side-by-side.

Especially that last part, storing different assemblies and different versions side by side in the same location, is why you should not try to inject project names or versions into the symbol share location. That's for the debugger to figure out.

Just to be clear, it doesn't have to live on a different server, the only thing required is that you enter a path to a share, it can even be a sub-folder of that share. so sometimes you see configurations like:

```
\\tfs\symbols\
\\tfs\builds\
```

Or

```
\\tfs\artifacts\symbols
\\tfs\artifacts\drops
```

But indeed, you could drop your symbols to a completely different server altogether:

```
\\tfs\builds
\\corporate\symbols
```

Or you could configure multiple distinct computer names for one system (or use multiple DNS records) and actually have the same server listen to:

```
\\tfs-symbols\share
\\tfs-builds\share
```

Or even register the shares at the Active Directory level, allowing you to just use

\tfs-symbols\
   \tfs-builds\

What you choose is all up to you, but make sure that the two paths of symbols and builds are eventually unique.

Comment: thanks for the reply. That helps. Drop location was a poor choice of words on my part when referring to symbols. I was simply trying to use some of the TFS variables to put the symbols in a separate folder parallel to the drop folder. Symbols and build output will always be in unique folders. We will not be providing the symbols to customers and will not make them available to anyone outside our development team.